# How to implement AoA/currentLocation with Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, position, bluetooth-lowenergy, currentlocation

I have developed an app where the executing device acts as a beacon. As a scan result, different BLE devices appear with their respective RSSI value.

Is it possible to use these RSSI values to determine the own current position with AoA? I have already read some documentation on this, but I have not found anything like an algorithm.

How can AoA be implemented?

Can someone tell me the necessary steps to do this?

Is triangulation also possible if the referenced 3 points are moving or do you only search for the 3 nearest points??

Comment: AoA needs to be implemented by all your devices to use it. AoA was first specified in BLE 5.1 but it is an optional feature.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554886/bluetooth-5-1-angle-of-arrival-backward-compatibility Triangulation of RSSI values is also possible with older devices. Keep in mind that RSSI only measures the signal strength and can vary drastically due to multiple different reasons

Comment: Also have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069009/how-do-you-pin-point-the-location-of-a-user-with-3-nodes-using-triangulation